# Display comments from a Facebook page link on my site's post page

Tags: facebook, plugin, comments

I am not sure if this is doable, but whenever I post a bit of news on my site, I will post a link on my Facebook fan page. Lately, I've noticed the whole discussion is happening on Facebook, with comments there being way bigger in numbers than on my page.

I notice FB has a Social Comments plugin. I was wondering if there was a way to embed comments from my Facebook fan page for a specific link with that plugin or any way otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

The [Social RSS application](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=23798139265) takes an RSS feed and every time something appears in that feed then it posts to your page. So if you can get an RSS feed from your news then that will do what you want.

The Social Comments plugin should combine comments on and off your site:

> Friends and people who like the Page
>   can then respond to the discussion by
>   liking or replying to the comment
>   directly in the News Feed on Facebook
>   or in the Comments Box on your site.
>   Threads stay synced across Facebook
>   and on the Comments Box on your site
>   regardless of where the comment was
>   made.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Right, this just means that if somebody comments on my site within the Facebook plugin, and then somebody responds to their comment on Facebook, both will be displayed.

Comment: That's how its supposed to work.